# Why does Phonegap Developer app not allow an app to open an external website when it works on desktop?

Tags: cordova

I have a simple app based on the Phonegap example that redirects to an external website. When I preview it on the desktop browser it works the way I want. When I load it in Phonegap Developer app (iOS) it doesn't do anything.

This has the access, allow-navigation, and allow-intent options set to allow any domain.

Is this just a limitation of Phonegap Developer that will work fine once I build the final app?

Comment: check the source of ur file in `config.xml` and it would help if u paste in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it in simulator by running the following command

```
cordova run ios
```

if problem still persists, then use [in-app browser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to open external links inside your app.